# Does kotlin's compareTo function support generics or Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: function, kotlin, generics

I want two Point objects to be compared without using equals, using compareTo like this:

```
    class  Point<T: Number>(val x: T, val y: T): Comparable<Point<T>>{
        override fun compareTo(other: Point<T>): Int {
            return compareValuesBy(this, other) {
                it<T>.x; it<T>.y
            }}
        }
```

Without the generic T, the code compiles. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I think that the <T> in the "it<T>. X" isn't necessary, but also, it's possible the compiler doesn't know that T is a Comparable?

Comment: The IDE says function invocation it<T>() is expected. And yes you're right. Number is not a Comparable. Perhaps there's no way to use generics here.

Comment: I was quick.  I swapped Number  for Comparable<T> and it works. Great ! thank you so much.

Comment: I think swapping number for Comparable<T> changes the behaviour slightly, since it will then allow non-numeric type arguments, which don't really make sense for a Point. See the "where" syntax in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know T is Comparable. You want

```
class  Point<T>(val x: T, val y: T): Comparable<Point<T>> where T: Number, T : Comparable<T> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Point<T>): Int {
        return compareValuesBy(this, other) {
            it.x; it.y
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the first problem. Another is that the line `it.x; it.y` does not make too much sense - it just ignores `x` and compares by `y` only. We need to provide two separate lambdas.

Comment: I know it's kind of foolish to compare to points if both of their coordinates are different, But this function has the side effect of telling me how further  a point is along the y axis. Oh, and how can I provide a second lambda?

Comment: @ntos You want to compare by `x` and if that is equal, compare by `y`? `compareValuesBy(this, other, { it.x }, { it.y })`

Comment: Thanks so much Sweeper. You're such an expert.